# DevExpress CallbackPanel takes forever to load data

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

I have a user control within a child page within a master page in which I need a panel to be displayed according to a check box's checked status.

I could use jQuery to accomplish this, but I need Ajax. Now if you are familiar with DX CallbackPanel you know that this control is just like the ASP.NET update panel.

When I check my check box I call a JavaScript function that calls the `CallbackPanel.PerformCallback()` function, and this function does what it does.

This is my user control:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="dx_auto_saxs_sales.ascx.cs" Inherits="bime.shokri.v1._0._1.Forms.dx_auto_saxs_sales" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="DevExpress.Web.v15.2, Version=15.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" Namespace="DevExpress.Web" TagPrefix="dx" %>
<script type="text/javascript">
var CallbackInQue = false;
function CheckBoxBimeSalQabl_CheckedChanged(s,e)
{
    if (ASPxCallbackPanel.InCallback())
        CallbackInQue = true;
    else
        ASPxCallbackPanel.PerformCallback();
}
function  OnEndCallback(s,e)
{
    if(CallbackInQue)
    {
        ASPxCallbackPanel.PerformCallback();
        CallbackInQue = false;
    }
}
</script>

<dx:ASPxCheckBox ID="ASPxCheckBox2" runat="server" Theme="MetropolisBlue" Text="بیمه نامه سال قبل دارد" Font-Names="yekan" CheckState="Unchecked" ClientInstanceName="ChechBoxBimeSalQabl">
            <ClientSideEvents CheckedChanged="CheckBoxBimeSalQabl_CheckedChanged" />
</dx:ASPxCheckBox>

<dx:ASPxCallbackPanel ID="ASPxCallbackPanel" runat="server" ClientInstanceName="ASPxCallbackPanel">

    <SettingsLoadingPanel Text="صبر کنید&amp;hellip;" />

    <ClientSideEvents EndCallback="OnEndCallback" />

    <PanelCollection>
        <dx:PanelContent runat="server">
            <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnl_formerBimeName">
                <div class="three fields">
                    <div class="field">
                        <label>تعداد سال های تخفیف  <span style="color: #c66050">●</span></label>
                        <dx:ASPxComboBox ID="ASPxComboBox7" runat="server" ValueType="System.String" BackColor="#efefef" CssClass="round-corner-control" Theme="MetropolisBlue" Font-Names="yekan" NullText="انتخاب کنید" Width="90%">
                            <Items>
                                <dx:ListEditItem Text="1 سال عدم خسارت" Value="0" />
                            </Items>
                        </dx:ASPxComboBox>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </asp:Panel>
        </dx:PanelContent>
    </PanelCollection>
</dx:ASPxCallbackPanel>
```

The purpose is to display `Panel(pnl_formerBimeName)` when CheckBox is checked.

Now this is my Page_Load(sender,object) method which is called asynchronous when Checkbox is checked:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pnl_formerBimeName.Visible = ASPxCheckBox2.Checked;
    }
```

Everything is OK until I deploy my website to my server. After that when I check the checkbox the "Loading..." the text appears and takes forever to complete. I really don't know why.

Just in case you wonder about this problem in action, I give you the mentioned page [here](http://behdoctor.ir/insurance/query/car).

Comment: You can try the tips given in this (old) technical support post: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q200495.